# Horizontal navigation sub menu alignment CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, submenu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP0kc.jpg

the navigation menu i have created using the CSS and Html code is not working correctly.
The alignment of the navigation menu is not perfect i want in this way :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4oPK.jpg 
I want to convert this to CSS..

Please help

```
        <style>
    /* Targeting both first and second level menus */

#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {

    background-color:red;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

/* Targeting the first level menu */
#nav {  
    top:150px;
    min-width:850px;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:0.5;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav > li > a {
}

/* Targeting the second level menu */
#nav li ul {
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    width:850px;
}
#nav li ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

/* Third level menu */
#nav li ul li ul{
    top: 0;
}
ul.child {
background-color:#FFF;  
}
/* A class of current will be added via jQuery */
#nav li.current > a {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    float:left;
}
/* CSS fallback */
#nav li:hover > ul.child {
    left:0;
    top:34px;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.grandchild  {
    display:block;
}
    </style>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Installations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Setups</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Created jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/RJxGu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I think this is what you want http://dabblet.com/gist/2792978

Simply remove `position: relative` from `#nav li` and give it to `#nav`.